# Flutter Frame load interrupted

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, webview-flutter

I am using Flutter web view and my code looks like this, after authentication I'm able to do authentication but there is one web resource error coming that is WebKitErrorDomain, error code 102, error Description : Frame load interrupted. Anyone knows how to fix this ios specific error.
[Here is code for whch I'm catching error in onWebViewResourceError method This is coming only on ios devices not on android.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFNJx.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzK16.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was loading a file that did not have `.html` as the file extension. Once I added that extension it worked.